# Object New button overriden with VF, loads continously

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a vf page that overrides a custom object's New Button. The original purpose for this was to run a custom check in the constructor, if that check passes I want them to be redirected to the New Record page for this object:

```
 public WasteAssesmentViewRedirect(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    System.debug('controller still called');
    this.controller = controller;

if(Constants.RESTRICTED_PROFILE_SET.contains(CommonUtility.getLoggedInUserProfile().Name))
   {
       ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'You are not allowed to create/edit from Salesforce'));
   }
}
```

---

```
<apex:page standardController="CustomObject__c" extensions="ObjectViewRedirect" showheader="true" action="{!redirect}">
    <apex:pagemessages escape="false"></apex:pagemessages>
</apex:page>
```

redirect method:

```
 public PageReference redirect(){
    //fix this to not redirect if the user is fails the above check.
    System.debug('Action redirect to new page02');
    //Get WA prefix
    Map<String,Schema.SObjectType> m = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    Schema.SObjectType s = m.get('CustomObject__c');
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = s.getDescribe();
    String waprefix = r.getKeyPrefix();
    //get  REC ID
    String rectypeid = GetRecordType.getRecID('CustomObject__c', 'REc Name');
    System.debug('wa prefix: '+waprefix);
    PageReference pr = new PageReference('/'+waprefix+'/e?RecordType='+rectypeid);
    pr.setRedirect(true);
    return pr;
}
```

When I click New from anywhere, the page loads continuosly, in the logs I can see this page override getting called over and over why is that ? In the URL I set the object prefix followed by /e. Does that not go to a new record page ? It shouldn't call itself should it ?

Answer (score 0):

Had to add nooverride:

```
PageReference pr = new PageReference('/'+waprefix+'/e?nooverride=1?RecordType='+rectypeid);
```